# Which file operations trigger directory modification time and date to change?

Tags: directory, time, ls

I have a directory named `IT-documentation`. Using `ls -l` in the terminal at its parent directory level yields (among numerous other lines)

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 robin robin 4096 Oct 31 08:02 IT-documentation
```

Now I say `cd IT-documentation`, then repeat `ls -l`. Among the numerous other lines this yields is

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 robin robin 4096 Nov  1 10:00 'How Tos'
```

On November 1 a file was in fact added to the subdirectory `How Tos`. So evidently changing something within a directory is not considered as modifying it. Or do I have a bug in my system (or a bee in my bonnet)?

Comment: Is `How Tos` a directory inside `IT-documentation`? Right now, what you are asking is very unclear. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1372862/edit) to clarify your question (otherwise, the moderators might close the question).

Answer (score 1):

Modifying a directory means adding, removing, or renaming something in the directory, or renaming or touching or changing the permissions on the directory itself.

Modifying or changing permissions on things in the directory do not modify the parent directory.

Comment: May I suggest the second line as: "Modifying or changing permissions or timestamps ..."?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, adding files only work for modification times in the *current* directory. So if you added a file in `IT-documentation`, the modification date of this directory would change.

However, if you add a file in a subdirectory (`How Tos`), this doesn't change `IT-documentation`, as no files are added here. Changing existing files and directories also does not trigger modification date changes, only adding, removing or renaming files will. I believe this is just how it works.

Please also see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1039003/linux-how-does-file-modification-time-affect-directory-modification-time-and-di).